Do I need to implement the server or client of SCIM2.0?
I want to implement Azure's SCIM, so is my service a server or client in the SCIM protocol?
I read the relevant documents of SCIM, and I think my service should be a server role, but I am a little unsure.
In addition, is there any mature golang library that can implement scim2.0?

Entra (formerly Azure AD) operates a SCIM 2.0 client, meaning you need to implement a SCIM service provider (server).
